# Как в docker compose собрать в одну сеть контейнеры из двух docker compose файлов

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Суть такая: Есть два файла `docker compose`.

- В первом хранится сам проект.
- Во втором хранятся его зависимости (пара нейронок на `tensorflow`).

И не очень хочется, чтобы команды: `docker-compose up/down/stop` затрагивали нейронки.

Как их собрать лишь на сетевом уровне, при помощи `network`, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте сеть вручную командой docker [network create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) и потом используйте ее с опцией `external: true` в обоих файлах:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    ...
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: existing-network
```

Можно использовать и сеть определенную в одном из двух docker-compose файлов

Comment: А обязательно использовать `network create`, из `docker-compose.yml` никак?

Comment: Да, можно использовать сеть из `docker-compose.yml`. Добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно решал похожую задачу, у меня есть несколько микросервисов в разных docker-compose. Условно назовем так, есть основной сервис с фронтом и бэком, есть сервис авторизации, это чисто API и есть админка это чисто фронтенд, который взаимодействует с авторизацией и основным сервисом по API. И вот мне понадобилось настроить из взаимодействие

Первый docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  api:
   ....
  frontend:
    ....
  pgsql:
    ....
  nginx:
    ....
```

Второй docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  api:
    ....
  pgsql:
    ....
  nginx:
    ....
```

Объединяющий docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx: //Здесь в настройках nginx проксирует запросы через location /auth/ и т.п. соответственно на нужные контейнеры
    ....
networks: 
  first_default: //Говорим, что есть внешняя сеть контейнеров других
    external: 
      name: first_default
      name: admin_default
  second_default:
    external: 
      name: second_default
  bridge_default: //Убей не помню зачем я мост сделал, но зачем то нужен был, поэтому оставлю, вдруг тоже пригодится
    driver: bridge
    name: bridge_services
```

Ну вот и все поднимаем объединяющий композ и с помощью docker exec -ti container-name /bin/sh заходим в него и пингуем интересующие контенйеры по имени, например:

ping first_service_api1

Если пинг есть, значит можно взаимодействовать